# Проблема с отступом при адаптивной верстке

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый день, уважаемые пользователи. Подскажите решение

```
$(document).ready(function(){   $("#benefit").on("click","a", function    (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate( {scrollTop: top-75}, 500 );
       });
```

Как видите при любом разрешение отступ от верхнего края 75px, как сделать что бы при разрешение менее 768px отступ был 30px, ну и соответственно более 768px отступ 75px.

Comment: Используйте конструкцию IF THEN ELSE.

Comment: if ($(window).width() < 768) {
   alert('Отступ 30px');
}
else {
   alert('Отступ 75px');
}

Comment: soledar10, Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы используете `JavaScript` для решения подобных задач?

Можно решить данную проблему подручными средствами  `CSS`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .yourElement {
         padding: someValue;
         //Or
         margin: someValue;
      }
}
```